# How to use a Many-to-Many through model in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I'm trying to achieve the general "Like" functionality in a social media website using Django and REST Framework, and a frontend in React.
Using a *Post* model to save all the posts, and I have a Many-to-Many field for storing the likes and created a *through* model as follows:

```
class PostLike(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AppUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey("Post", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AppUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    caption = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    edited_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(
        AppUser, related_name="post_user", blank=True, through=PostLike
    )
```

(**AppUser is a custom auth model used**)

Similarly, I have created serializers and viewsets for the above models:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = "__all__"


class PostLikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PostLike
        fields = "__all__"

class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer


class PostLikeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = PostLike.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostLikeSerializer
```

My question is, how do I "like" or remove an existing "like" from a post using API calls?
One method I know is to just make a POST request to the **PostLike** endpoint using the user PK and the post PK to create a PostLike instance, but I don't know a way to "remove" a like using the same method.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `APIView` instead of `ViewSet` like this:

```
from rest_framework import views

class PostLikeApiView(views.APIView):
    serializer = PostLikeSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        user = serializer.data['user']
        post = serializer.data['post']
    
        post_like_obj = PostLike.objects.filter(user=user, post=post)
        if post_like_obj.exists():
            post_like_obj.delete()
            result = 'unliked'
        else:
            PostLike.objects.create(user=user, post=post)
            result = 'liked'
            
        return Response(
            {
                'result': result,
            },
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK
        )
            
    else:
        return Response(
            serializer.errors,
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        )
```

Comment: Hey, thanks alot for this solution. The code works while adding a **like**, but when deleting a like it throws an error saying '`create()` must return an object'. Any help with that?

Comment: thanks alot, I found a similar way to solve this problem.